# How to resolve file "<input>", line 1 syntaxerror: invalid syntax?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm a beginner in Python. I tried to resolve this error but I couldn't. This code worked before but not anymore. I run the code in PyCharm and getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/MJavad/Desktop/test.py", line 3, in <module>
b = float(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I ran CMD and had also an error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
    python test.py 1 2
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone help, please? This is my code:

```
import sys
import math
b = float(sys.argv[1])
c = float(sys.argv[2])
f = b * b - 4.0 * c
d = math.sqrt(f)
print((-b + d) / 2.0)
print((-b - d) / 2.0)
```

and this is the code and error in PyCharm:
[image]

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  We need the context of your command line that will allow us to reproduce your problem.  Your error message is from the command-line interpreter, not Python.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I'm not the poster.  Also, note that the `cmd` posting *does* specify two parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is confusion about how Python code can be executed and processed.

1. On the one hand, there is the Python interpreter in the interactive mode. This is usually started with the command `python` (without arguments) and then you have the possibility to execute Python code directly in an interactive Python specific shell. This distinguishes Python from other languages that need to be compiled first to execute code. Further information are available in the official [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#interactive-mode).
2. On the other hand, Python can also be executed in such a way that not the interpreter with an interactive shell is started, but a file is read and processed. This is usually done with the command `python` together with the path to the Python file as argument, e.g. `python test.py`. See also the [documentation about using Python](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#command-line).

With this knowledge the problems that have happened to you can now be explained and solved:

If you are simply starting the Python interpreter in interactive mode (without any further arguments), you don't have access to the command line arguments any more, for example:

```sh
$ python3.8  # or whatever your command is, maybe only python or python3
Python 3.8.0 (default, Oct 28 2019, 16:14:01) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys; sys.argv
['']
```

As you can see, there isn't really a usable information in `argv`. And that is your problem: The arguments aren't successfully loaded into `sys.argv`. So an index error happened, because the arguments are simply missing:

```sh
$ python3.8
Python 3.8.0 (default, Oct 28 2019, 16:14:01) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.argv[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The only difference to your example is that you have already provided the path to the script, because it's `File "C:/Users/MJavad/Desktop/test.py", line 3, in <module>` instead of `File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>`. So you have started the program via `python test.py`, but also without any further arguments which would be loaded into `sys.argv` in the program, see:

```sh
$ python3.8 test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    b = float(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Your `sys.argv` now looks like this: `['test.py']`, but still no index positions 1 and 2 available. So you have to invoke python also with additional arguments which will be passed into `sys.argv`:

```sh
$ python3.8 test.py 1 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    d = math.sqrt(f)
ValueError: math domain error
```

And it worked! Ok, you have another exception, but it's in line 6 and every line before was successfully processed, also the command line arguments. Now you can proceed to debug your program, i.e. start programming or trying other parameters than `1` and `2` etc.

So that's the theory. Since you're also using PyCharm and have the "Terminal", the "Run configuration" and a "Python Console" available, things get a bit more complicated:

1. The "Terminal" should have a prompt available if you start one. This prompt shouldn't be a prompt from the Python interpreter (normally prefixed by `>>>`). It should be a terminal prompt (normally prefixed by an `$` at the end), where you can also start a python interpreter in interactive mode or start a python program as described above. This "Terminal" is a terminal emulator given you by PyCharm and can also do other things for you, not only starting python programs. See the [PyCharm documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/terminal-emulator.html) for more information.
2. The "Python Console" is a similar Python interpreter you also can get if starting `python` from the "Terminal". But then, you already started the interactive mode of the interpreter and there are no possibilities to pass command line arguments (maybe somewhere, but not as default). See the [PyCharm documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/console-python-console.html#) for more information.
3. If you're using an IDE like PyCharm, you should normally start the program as recommended by the IDE. In this case, you're writing a file and start the file neither by running the "Terminal", nor going into an interactive Python shell. Instead of this, you have to configure the IDE "Run" as described in the [PyCharm documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration.html#) or as you can see here:

   [image: run configuration]

   This is just the GUI way of calling `python C:/Users/MJavad/Desktop/test.py 1 2` directly inside PyCharm.

So I would recommend that you're only starting your programs via option 3 (via "Run" configuration or "DEBUG" configuration). You only have to pay attention, running the right configuration (see if the path is the correct one and the parameters are right).

It is not normal to have a Python prompt (`>>>`) directly after starting a "Terminal", though. And inside interactive mode of Python's interpreter, you simply cannot start a python script, because you're already in a python interpreter, for example:

```sh
$ python3.8
Python 3.8.0 (default, Oct 28 2019, 16:14:01) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> python test.py 1 2
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python test.py 1 2
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I should also mention that you can pass arguments into python interactive mode, for example (the `-` stands for `<stdin>`):

```sh
$ python3.8 - hello world
Python 3.8.0 (default, Oct 28 2019, 16:14:01) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys; sys.argv
['-', 'hello', 'world']
>>>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. i corrected the parameter and used "Python Console" but unfortunately it shows up first error. the other question i have is that i wrote this code yesterday and it worked very well but today i wrote it again and it not works! is it possible that some necessary files are removed because of my antivirus?

Comment: @MJavad I've updated my answer. Am I on the right track? (btw: getting this problem solved would lead you to potentially other errors in the code itself, but then you have a proper setup and then you can really start debugging and programming.

Comment: I've written this code again and used "Terminal" in PyCharm but it not worked. Not only this code, but other example i wrote, didn't work and <stdin> error showed in Terminal in PyCharm

Comment: I've updated the question and add picture from Pycharm. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Your Terminal is strange, you have already started a python interpreter in your terminal. Dont know if you started it or PyCharm... So you cannot access the command line arguments any more in the terminal window. The terminal should give you a Terminal, not a Python interpreter (there is Python console for this). What happens if you start a new Terminal? Are there ">>>" in front (indicating a prompt inside python interpreter)? Alternative: use PyCharm Runner config. (Play Button) or run `exit()` first in the terminal then `python test 1 2`. You need a normal prompt in Terminal window, though.

Comment: thank you very much! I did as you said for Terminal and changed something and worked! i corrected the "Terminal" in PyCharm. and in setting for new project, there was no existing interpreter, so i chose Python 3.8 for this. and now codes work in Terminal without error.

Comment: @MJavad Glad that I could help! It would be nice if you can mark the answer as accepted. I also refactored my answer and give a lot of explanation in addition. If this is not as good as the answer before, let me know, then I would simply restore the answer before.